# Open a link with different browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

When I click a link, I want to choose a browser to open only for that link?

Is it possible to make a mini program for this aim with c#?

Do you have any idea?

For example for Firefox there is an add-ons which is called Open With. 
But I should make it from Chrome, IE, Firefox even Safari..

Note: I did not decide which tags should I use..

Comment: You should provide some more details about the context of the problem. From where would you click a link, from a website or a Windows program that you wrote?

Comment: That's not very nice to your end user, forcing him to open a link with the browser of your choice. Unless you had something else in mind? Also - how do you ensure that the user has your browser installed? In any case - the plugin/addon you write is only going to work with one browser, you'll need to port it to all the others in your list. What about Opera? What about Konqueror? What about mobile devices running their own browser?

Comment: Why do you have both asp.net and winforms as tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("browserChoice.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com"`

You can find the install path for the various browsers by using the registry.  Then it's a case of using the above call with the URL you want.

**EDIT: This assumes you're NOT in ASP.NET!  You cannot control what browser a user uses in a web page**